# Slow sql-server database query. How to improve

Tags: sql-server

The query below average of 21 seconds to complete. The total rows in the records table is 132,167

How can I make the query faster?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101) AS dt,
       LEFT(itemid, 3)               AS store,
       Sum(checkamount)              AS amountpaid,
       Sum(finalprice)               AS sales
FROM   records
WHERE  Dateadd(month, -1, Getdate()) <= dended
       AND highbidder LIKE '%href%'
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)
ORDER  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)
```

I can't share the data for obvious reasons. The records table has index.

There might be a lot of things involved on why the query is slow. My main concern is to improve the query and make it run faster.

Database runs on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
(Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

[image]

Comment: Any possibility to change this somehow highbidder LIKE '%href%'? Since it has % in the beginning, index won't be used?

Comment: How much of the data matches criteria Dateadd(month, -1, Getdate()) <= dended? I assume that field is indexed, but is the query using it?

Comment: Also, is dended a datetime? I would recommend keeping it as datetime and letting the front end do formatting.

Comment: The biggest problem is doing a GROUP BY and ORDER BY on a computed value. If you just left it as a datetime and let the client format it as they wished, you'd have a significantly better performing query.

Comment: _What_ columns are in the the index on the `records` table? When you use CTR-L to observe the query plan, which element has the biggest percentage? Even better, post the query plan.

Comment: @SeanLange dended is datetime

Comment: @Nick the ctrl-L is new to me and today I learned : )

Comment: I don't know the correct way to share my query plan. I inserted it in my question or you can directly see it here http://i.stack.imgur.com/NrkKr.png

Comment: Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(30),[instant].[dbo].[records].[dended],101)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

This is the warning after executing query plan

Comment: @JamesZ 

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101) AS dt,
       LEFT(itemid, 3)               AS store,
       Sum(checkamount)              AS amountpaid,
       Sum(finalprice)               AS sales
FROM   records
WHERE  Dateadd(month, -1, Getdate()) <= dended

GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)
ORDER  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)

GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)
ORDER  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, dended, 101),
          LEFT(itemid, 3)


Returns 0 records according to query plan

Comment: See that green text in your query plan? it's recommending you create an index which will make **90%** difference. You can right click on it and get a definition. Your query could really do with a rewrite too. Indexes are the 'easy way out' and should not be abused but have a go at it.

Comment: I created the index and now the query runs at 3 seconds which I guess @nick.mcdermaid sugggestion solves my problem. It took me time to acknowledge comments and suggestions coz of database permission issues I have to go around.

Comment: Just remember: you should really understand some of the rewrite suggestions posted here also.

Answer (score 0):

How good is `"Dateadd(month, -1, Getdate()) <= dended"` at filtering the data? Does this result in most rows or a few? The LIKE statement used for highbidder cannot use indexes. Adding a full-text index on that column and using that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this approach - move out calculated fields outside the where and the group sections:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT a.dt,a.store,SUM(a.amountpaid) [amountpaid],SUM(a.sales) [sales]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.dended, 101) [dt], 
        LEFT(r.itemid, 3) [store], 
        r.checkamount [amountpaid], 
        r.finalprice [sales],
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('href',r.highbidder)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsValid]
    FROM records r
    WHERE r.dended >= @DateTime
) a
WHERE a.IsValid = 1
GROUP BY a.dt,a.store
ORDER BY a.dt,a.store
```

**UPDATE:**
If for some reason creation of a nonclustered index on main table is restricted (for example to avoid performance hit on update/insert or if table has low fillfactor or so) - in this case the data can be copied to a temp table and index can be created on the temp table:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT r.dended, r.itemid, r.checkamount, r.finalprice, r.highbidder
INTO #Records
FROM records r

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempRecords ON #Records (dended) INCLUDE (itemid, highbidder)

SELECT a.dt,a.store,SUM(a.amountpaid) [amountpaid],SUM(a.sales) [sales]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.dended, 101) [dt], 
        LEFT(r.itemid, 3) [store], 
        r.checkamount [amountpaid], 
        r.finalprice [sales],
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('href',r.highbidder)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsValid]
    FROM #Records r
    WHERE r.dended >= @DateTime
) a
WHERE a.IsValid = 1
GROUP BY a.dt,a.store
ORDER BY a.dt,a.store

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Records') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP INDEX #Records.IDX_TempRecords
    DROP TABLE #Records
END
```

If the time is still unacceptable - you need to rethink about way of data store in general. Why it is stored in this way. The best thing is to create extra columns on "record" table and insert "pre-resolved" data into the table to avoid converting it on a fly later on.
I mean extra columns:

```
ALTER TABLE records ADD [dt] VARCHAR(255), [Store] VARCHAR(MAX) and [IsValidHighbidder] BIT
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Is it similar time. or slower, or better, but still slow? Most likely all further improvements require (re)indexing work.

Comment: it was extremely slow than the current query. It runs more than 4 minutes before getting the result. The current query took 24 seconds.

Comment: I'll repeat my comment..... See that green text in your query plan? it's recommending you create an index which will make 90% difference. You can right click on it and get a definition. Your query could really do with a rewrite too. Indexes are the 'easy way out' and should not be abused but have a go at it

Comment: @VitalyBorisov the updated query now runs 8 seconds compared to the previous query you shared. I went to creating the index as suggested by nick and now the query runs 3 seconds. I appreciate the suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer also noticed that index for dended is missing, that probably makes a big difference. If that field isn't updated really often, there shouldn't be big impacts on creating it.

Adding those other columns as included field depends basically on how many rows this query on average finds (=how many keylookups it has to make if those aren't in that field). If the amount of rows fetched is low, adding them to the index too is probably pointless.

If there's other similar queries that use dended as criteria, you should probably check them too, if other fields would be beneficial in this index.